# Adobe AIR Extension for Dreamweaver fails to connect to timestamp server

Tags: air, adobe, dreamweaver

I'm having issues with creating an AIR file from an Adobe AIR HTML/JavaScript project.

I've installed the Adobe AIR Extension for Dreamweaver CS5.5 and I also have the latest x86 version of the Java Development Kit installed (which should include the Java Runtime Environment). I'm using Windows 7 (x64).

After self-signing a digital certificate through the extension, I attempted to build the project into an AIR file. However, I encountered this dialog:

> There was an error connecting to the timestamp server. You may not have a connection to the network, or the server itself may have a problem.
>
> Click Retry to try again.
>
> Click Disable to create the AIR file with timestamping temporarily disabled. If you disable timestamping, the AIR application will fail to install when the digital certificate expires.

I checked my proxy settings in both the Java control panel and Internet Explorer, but nothing should interfere with Dreamweaver's connection. I also disabled Windows Firewall and tried another network connection, both to no avail.

After some research, I found a suggestion stating that the Geotrust timestamp server may be temporarily down. Despite this, the error still persists after I've waited a day.

Can somebody help me resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Java SE version 7 was installed on my computer, but version 6 was the latest version supported by the Adobe AIR tools. I downgraded to version 6 and the timestamp generation went smoothly.